# How can I set the equivalence arrows to be left-justified but the equation to be centered?

Tags: amsmath

Such that every line begins with an equivalence arrow but the equation is centered. I would be perfect, if I could align the equations at the equal-sign (like in an align-environment with "&").

Answer (score 2):

Did you try something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        &       &   x^2         &= 2x-1 \\
        &\iff   &   x^2-2x+1    &= 0    \\ 
        &\iff   &   (x-1)^2     &= 0    \\
        &\iff   &   x-1         &= 0    \\
        &\iff   &   x           &=1 
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: align with iff]